# Not showing desired map

Tags: java, android

When I run the app, I get the world map, where you can see all the countries. But this is not what I want, I want it to show the map of my country or city as an example. Is there a way to do this? This is my code so far. I don't think the xml code should be necassary for this?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private GoogleMap gMap;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private Location location, g;
    private double lati, longi;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        gMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();    
//      gMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        System.out.println("Last known location: " + location); 
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void showUsersPosition(View v) {
        gMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        if(location != null) {
            lati = location.getLatitude();
            longi = location.getLongitude();                
        }
        gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lati, longi)).title("You are here"));
    }
}
```

I also have added a button, where I want to show the users location when this button is clicked. This happens in the method "showUsersPosition". But at this point, Location is null, even though I try to set it when the app is beeing started. Can anyone see why it is null? When the gMap.setMyLocation(true) is called, a symbole appears at the right corner, and if I click on this, it will show me my position. But I want it so that it does this when I click the button.

So the questions again are:
1. How to show the map of my country or city, and not the world map?
2. Why is Location null?
3. How do I make it show my exact location when the button is clicked

Answer (score 1):

1)
You can  use this on your fragment declaration to set the default latitude and longitude.

```
  map:cameraTargetLat="Your Latitude"
  map:cameraTargetLng="Your Longitude"
```

Do not forget to put `xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` on your fragment if it is not there.

2) From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getBestProvider%28android.location.Criteria,%20boolean%29):

> If the provider is currently disabled, null is returned.

Is the GPS turned on?. Also, you should use the new [Location API](http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html).

3) The exactness of your Location will be based on the Provider used to get the Location. One of the advantages of using the new [Fused Provider](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html) is that the system will try to get the best Location possible for you.

Comment: For 2) is it possible that 'lastKnowLocation' is causing this if there none? I got the impression he can use the button in maps that snaps to your location, but initially it fails as there is no last location?

Comment: On the docs it says that it will return null if the Provider is turned off. I am pretty sure that for "My Location" button Google uses their new Location API which will get the best Location based on the given conditions (i.e. is GPS on? is WiFi on? can I get it of my Network connection? is lastKnwownLocation() my best bet?). This is all done by the Fused Location Provider.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, that's what I was thinking, but there's always device specific weirdness around location handling. HTC I'm looking at you!

Comment: Doing this: map:cameraTargetLat="Your Latitude" will require me to hardcode latitude and longitude, and this is not what I want, since the user can be in different areas.


Adding the xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" to my fragment doesn't work, since it says "Unexpected namespace prefix "xmlns" found for tag fragment. And yea, my GPS is turned on, and I'm on wifi. I also tried turning off wifi

Comment: Then, you should ensure that you are getting a Location and Animate the Camera to the location you want.